# Socket.io returning Uncaught RangeError and literal javascript code on server, but works fine locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, openshift

I'm writing a server/client using Node.js and Socket.io and hosting it with OpenShift. The client and server are connecting properly when I run the code locally, but once on OpenShift, the client is refusing to connect.

Locally, the request `http://127.0.0.1:8000/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1409632875121-110` will return an appropriate JSON response. On the server however, the request is (**EDIT**) timing out.

(**EDIT:** formerly the error was returning literally the code content of `socket.io/index.js` and throwing: "Uncaught RangeError: Invalid string length" at `sockets.io.js:3947`)

**Server**

```
    self.server = require('http').createServer(self.app);
    self.io = require('socket.io').listen(self.server);
    self.io.set('transports', ['websocket', 'polling', 'xhr-polling', 'jsonp-polling']);

    ...

    self.routes['/myip'] = function(req, res){
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        res.send("" + self.ipaddress);
    }

    ...

    self.app.listen(self.port, self.ipaddress, function() {
        console.log('%s: Node server started on %s:%d ...',
                    Date(Date.now() ), self.ipaddress, self.port);
    });

    self.server.listen("8000", self.ipaddress, function(){
        console.log("Starting another server");
    });
```

**Client**

```
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', '/myip', false);  // I want it synchronous
    request.send(null);

    if (request.status === 200) {
        var ip = request.responseText
        console.log(ip);
        socket = io.connect("http://" + ip + ":8000");
    }else{
        socket = io.connect();
        alert('There were issues connecting to server. Expect odd issues.');
    }
    socket.emit('set-host');
```

Any thoughts as to why this is working on localhost but not when hosted?

**EDIT:** I believe the "string length" error is really a symptom of the client not finding a server running. I changed the code (reflected above) to ensure that the IP the client connects to is the same as on the server. Still, works locally. Breaks down when uploaded.

**EDIT 2:** Using the IP address or a the literal URL to connect on the client is both giving a connection timeout error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using your openshift url (something like app-domain.rhcloud.com) not the ip address of the server, since everything is hosted using virtual hosts.  Also, your server should listen on port 8080, not 8000, but the client should access it on port 8000, using your openshift url.

Comment: Using the literal url causes the "Uncaught RangeError" which I believe is the client not finding the server. When I change to the IP, I get a timeout error instead, which is likely also not finding the server.

Comment: Your server should be listening on port 8080, not 8000, but it is accessed from the outside on port 8000.

Comment: Node.js is currently serving on port 8080, and so the Socket.io server can't be started on the same port. I tried serving on 9080 and accessing on 9000 but that is still timing out as well.

Comment: Here is an example of a node.js application that serves both http and websockets on port 8080 at the same time: https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/openshift-nodejs-http-and-websocket-example

Comment: Also, the only externally accessible ports are 22, 80, 443, 8000, and 8443, and everything accept for 22 are proxied to port 8080 internally